# Who uses 'inveritable' and 'inveritably'?

Tags: meaning, slang

Does anyone here use *inveritable* in the sense of *unavoidable*, or *the usual occurrence*?

I have heard people say things like:

> It was **inveritable** that the manager would have to leave after the team lost 10-0.

People will speak of an 'inveritable outcome'.

> He **inveritably** arrives half an hour late.

Perhaps I am confusing this with *invariably*?

I was surprised to find that I could not find the word in a mainstream dictionary, only in an on-line urban dictionary.

Does anyone else use it in this way?

Comment: Probably a mishearing (theirs, not yours) of *inevitable*.

Comment: Perhaps, then, a Spoonerism, which at some point I had accepted as a valid word. Amazing, you learn something every day!

Comment: I like the theory of mixing up (or inadvertently blending) _invariably_ and _inevitably_. So, _"Invariably, inevitably, he shows up late_," becomes, _"Inveritably, he shows up late."_

Comment: I use it. I have read it in books written by English authors, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 4):

"Inveritably" is most likely a Spoonerism of "inevitably" and "invariably", with "inveritable" being the adjective form.  They sound sophisticated, so people use them.

The words are given pseudo-legitimacy by the fact that "veritable" (as in "veritable feast") *is* a valid word, and adding the prefix "in" to it would appear to be a legitimate transformation. However, even though the "rules" for adding "in" to a word to derive a new word are quite obscure, the most straight-forward derived meaning of "inveritable" would be "not genuine", which is entirely opposite of the "accepted" meaning.  This further re-enforces the likelihood that the word is a Spoonerism arising out of ignorance rather than a traditionally derived neologism.

Comment: I think you are probably right.

Answer (score 3):

"inveritable" is presumably the antonym of "veritable", not false, unreal, or imaginary, and I would suggest that it was used mistakenly when "inevitable" was meant.

Answer (score 1):

As Urban Dict. suggests [inveritable:](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Inveritable)  is used with the meaning you describe. It is a slang expression I have rarely heard.

> - n. It is used as a slang/secretive term for a verifiably, extremely, 100% undeniably, more so than average, slammin hot girl.
> - adj. Used to describe a situation that is verifiably extremely, 100% undeniably, more so than average, slammin hot.

Comment: That is how I have heard it used, but it has always struck me as a sophisticated word, not something one would associate with street slang. I was surprised not to find it in a mainstream dictionary.

Comment: Well, it actually may sound sophisticated and,  who knows.  it might be one day :)).

Comment: Doesn't seem a great fit (*unavoidable* is not the same thing as *undeniably*). I think TimLymington's suggestion of a mis-heard "inevitable" is more likely.